# Given the sides of a triangle, find $\tan\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)$ and $\tan\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

In a triangle the sides are given as $a=25$ units, $b=52$ units and $c=63$ units.

The problem is to find $\tan\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)$ and $\tan\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)$ where $A$ is the angle opposite to side $a$ and $B$ is the angle opposite to side $b$.

Firstly I thought that the triangle is a right-angled triangle but after calculation I found that $c^2\ne a^2+b^2$.

So I have no idea to solve this problem.

Please help.

Comment: Plot the incentre! Spot the angle A/2 in a right triangle.  (i.e tanA/2 = r/(s-a))

Comment: @Rigel Sir kindly elaborate you technique.

Comment: If you know the sides, you can find the area using Heron's formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron's_formula. Then writing the area as half of the product of two sides and the sinus of the angles between, you can find the sinus of the angle (and the $\cos$ if required). For the half angle, you must use the half angle formula: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Half-AngleFormulas.html

Comment: Use law of cosines, it might be harder but is elementary

Comment: It isn't sir! It must be clear now from Chip's and Dutta's way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following are the properties of a triangle.

Let **a,b,c** denote the three sides of the triangle and **A,B,C** be their opposite angles. 
We have $$\tan \frac{A}{2} =\sqrt{\frac{(s-b)(s-c)}{s(s-a)}}$$
 $$\tan \frac{B}{2} =\sqrt{\frac{(s-a)(s-c)}{s(s-b)}}
$$
 $$\tan \frac{C}{2} =\sqrt{\frac{(s-b)(s-a)}{s(s-c)}}$$
where $s= \frac{a+b+c}{2}$

Now u can calculate them!

Comment: Nice. These formulas are new for me.

Comment: Its from properties of triangle. The proof is also easy